# Include gspread module using py2exe, pyinstaller

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller, gspread

I have created a python application which fetches data from a google spreadsheet and performs the required operation and outputs files with the data accordingly. The application works fine through my ide and the console. I'm using `gspread and Tkinter` for accessing the google sheets and for the GUI respectively.

However when I try to create it into an exe. I keep running into errors.

First I tried using py2exe but I keep getting the error
`ImportError: No module named gspread`
My setup.py is

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console = ["app.py"], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["gspread"]}})`
```

and I run it with the command `python setup.py py2exe`

I also tried pyInstaller using the command `pyinstaller app.py` and I get the same error. Although in this case the command executes completely and the exe is created but when I run it the console window flashes saying
`ImportError: No module named gspread`

I also tried using cx_freeze to create the executable. The command I use is
`python setup.py build_exe -s -p gspread,json,oauth2client.client,os`

This creates the executable but I get the error

`I\O operation failed`

for line 187 of my code

```
credentials = oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
credentials = credentials.create_scoped(['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'])
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)  #line 187
```

which I've caught using a try/except block on line 187

Comment: The error was that gspread was installed as a .egg in the `Lib\site-packages` folder in the python installation and py2exe does not work with exe files. So I unzipped the egg file and pasted the unzipped gspread folder there and ran the py2exe command and it worked however i still get the error now which I was getting when I used pyInstaller

Comment: stick with pyinstaller and create yourself a spec file. Add gspread to the hidden imports. Come back, if error still persists. Post the build log in case of errors.